# markdown is not being converted properly to html

Tags: python, markdown

I have some markdown text stored in a certain table column in my database(sqlite) and am trying to convert it to markdown; Here is a sample of one of the full contents of one of the table cells which i got after running these two commands( `.mode line` and `SELECT content FROM post LIMIT 1` ).

````
content = **Lorem ipsum** dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a arcu eget tortor venenatis laoreet. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc nec ipsum eu massa pharetra scelerisque. Maecenas accumsan ex nisl, ac condimentum lorem porttitor a. Nullam posuere ligula ac mauris cursus mattis.

Proin ut hendrerit lorem. Donec imperdiet risus in dui vulputate, vitae volutpat arcu ultricies. Quisque et pellentesque lectus, eutempus nisi. Sed vel felis nibh. Duis eu lorem non odio blandit ornare. Mauris facilisis, urna nec condimentum sodales, nulla nisi aliquam ante, eget pulvinar nibh sem ut ipsum.

Pellentesque vel justo ut felis eleifend tincidunt. Pellentesque vel porttitor nisl. Fusce eu ligula id arcu volutpat elementum quis quis arcu.

```python
@main.route('/<slug>')
def show_post(slug):
    entities = (Post.title, Post.created_at, Post.cover_image,
                Post.content)
    post = Post.query.with_entities(*entities) \
        filter(Post.published == 1). \
        filter(Post.slug == slug).first()
    if not post:
        abort(404)
```
````

When i take that content and i try it through my python shell by trying the following code

````
from markdown import markdown
s = '''**Lorem ipsum** dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a arcu eget tortor venenatis laoreet. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc nec ipsum eu massa pharetra scelerisque. Maecenas accumsan ex nisl, ac condimentum lorem porttitor a. Nullam posuere ligula ac mauris cursus mattis.

Proin ut hendrerit lorem. Donec imperdiet risus in dui vulputate, vitae volutpat arcu ultricies. Quisque et pellentesque lectus, eutempus nisi. Sed vel felis nibh. Duis eu lorem non odio blandit ornare. Mauris facilisis, urna nec condimentum sodales, nulla nisi aliquam ante, eget pulvinar nibh sem ut ipsum.

Pellentesque vel justo ut felis eleifend tincidunt. Pellentesque vel porttitor nisl. Fusce eu ligula id arcu volutpat elementum quis quis arcu.

```python
@main.route('/<slug>')
def show_post(slug):
    entities = (Post.title, Post.created_at, Post.cover_image,
                Post.content)
    post = Post.query.with_entities(*entities) \
        filter(Post.published == 1). \
        filter(Post.slug == slug).first()
    if not post:
        abort(404)
```
'''
markdown(s)
````

I get the following output

```
<p><strong>Lorem ipsum</strong> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a arcu eget tortor venenatis laoreet. In hac hab
itasse platea dictumst. Nunc nec ipsum eu massa pharetra scelerisque. Maecenas accumsan ex nisl, ac condimentum lorem porttitor a. N
ullam posuere ligula ac mauris cursus mattis.</p>\n<p>Proin ut hendrerit lorem. Donec imperdiet risus in dui vulputate, vitae volutp
at arcu ultricies. Quisque et pellentesque lectus, eutempus nisi. Sed vel felis nibh. Duis eu lorem non odio blandit ornare. Mauris
facilisis, urna nec condimentum sodales, nulla nisi aliquam ante, eget pulvinar nibh sem ut ipsum.</p>\n<p>Pellentesque vel justo ut
 felis eleifend tincidunt. Pellentesque vel porttitor nisl. Fusce eu ligula id arcu volutpat elementum quis quis arcu.</p>\n<p><code
>python\n@main.route('/&lt;slug&gt;')\ndef show_post(slug):\n    entities = (Post.title, Post.created_at, Post.cover_image,\n
         Post.content)\n    post = Post.query.with_entities(*entities)         filter(Post.published == 1).         filter(Post.slug
 == slug).first()\n    if not post:\n        abort(404)</code></p>
```

Everything seems fine, till the last part, where i would expect something like
`<pre><code class="lang-python">...</code></pre>` as explained [here](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet) with the `...` representing the python code in-between the tags **but** instead am getting this `<p><code>...</code></p>`.

What could be causing this, is it the markdown library or something else?

Comment: Where does that documentation say that `markdown` adds `class="lang-python"`?

Comment: @Barmar I don't it does say that but when i try the same input using the `php` markdown to html converters, it produces the correct output so my guess there is a problem somewhere in how it's being converted in python

Comment: It says that highlighting and languages recognized depends on the renderer you're using.

Comment: @Barmar fair enough, which renderer would recommend in python

Comment: You seem to have a problem that's duplicating your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fenced code blocks are not [standard Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/). Therefore, you need to [enable](https://python-markdown.github.io/reference/#extensions) the [extension](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/fenced_code_blocks/) for them to get parsed properly:

```
markdown(s, extensions=['fenced_code'])
```

Which renders the following output:

```
<p><strong>Lorem ipsum</strong> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a arcu eget tortor venenatis laoreet. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc nec ipsum eu massa pharetra scelerisque. Maecenas accumsan ex nisl, ac condimentum lorem porttitor a. Nullam posuere ligula ac mauris cursus mattis.</p>
<p>Proin ut hendrerit lorem. Donec imperdiet risus in dui vulputate, vitae volutpat arcu ultricies. Quisque et pellentesque lectus, eutempus nisi. Sed vel felis nibh. Duis eu lorem non odio blandit ornare. Mauris facilisis, urna nec condimentum sodales, nulla nisi aliquam ante, eget pulvinar nibh sem ut ipsum.</p>
<p>Pellentesque vel justo ut felis eleifend tincidunt. Pellentesque vel porttitor nisl. Fusce eu ligula id arcu volutpat elementum quis quis arcu.</p>
<pre><code class="python">@main.route('/&lt;slug&gt;')
def show_post(slug):
    entities = (Post.title, Post.created_at, Post.cover_image,
                Post.content)
    post = Post.query.with_entities(*entities) \
        filter(Post.published == 1). \
        filter(Post.slug == slug).first()
    if not post:
        abort(404)
</code></pre>
```